# Why the result when i get the systemLayoutSizeFittingSize of tableviewcell is always zero?

Tags: ios, uitableview

The tableview cell is pretty complicated, there's one label that can change dynamically due to its content.

```
MyTaskTableViewCell *cell=[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
[self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath withCellIndentifier:cellIdentifier];
[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
NSLog(@"%f",[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height);
```

it shows in screen is right ,the content is tight there are blank lines between the end line of content and the bottom of cell. but the height always output 0, i cannot dynamically set the cell height, what's going on?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to calculate the height, auto layout will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to set the height of a cell view is with
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

If you want to have a dynamic height you have to do something in this function.

Comment: This is not the only way. If all rows have the same height, simply set the table view's `rowHeight` property instead.

Comment: Yes,in this function i want to get [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height so i can return the height value. but the value is always 0, i am confused

Comment: @maddy yes but the height of the cells cannot be dynamic in this case.

Comment: @leizh007 the heightForRowAtIndexPath is call before cellForRowAtIndexPath and only the value return by heightForRowAtIndexPath is used for set the height of the cell. You have to put the height of the cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yes i did that.in height for row at indexpath i dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and set the cell content
[self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath withCellIndentifier:cellIdentifier]; and then i get the value  [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height but it is always 0